# In Python is there a way to substitute part of the instruction by a string variable?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want display the data of the items listed in the ***show_list*** array.  Obviously this code won't work.  Any easy way to make it work?

```
import panda as pd
show_list=['Apple', 'Orange']
data = {
  "Apple": [1,2,3],
  "Banana": [4,5,6],
  "Orange": [7,8,9]
}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
for item in show_list:
  print(df.item)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need panda for anything like this, but are you looking for something like `for item in show_list: print(data[item])`?

Comment: Did you try `df[item]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just do `df[show_list]` it'll display it.

```py
In [1]: df[show_list]
Out[1]:
   Apple  Orange
0      1       7
1      2       8
2      3       9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the columns you want by passing their names to df

```
print(df[show_list])
```

The output will be

```
      Apple  Orange
   0      1       7
   1      2       8
   2      3       9
```

If you have to do some operations with data in those columns you can do this

```
for (columnName, columnData) in df.items():
    if columnName in show_list:
        print('Column Name : ', columnName)
        print('Column Contents : ', columnData.values)
            for value in columnData.values:
                # Do something with the value
```

Or

```
for item in show_list:
    for index in range(0, len(df[item])):
        print(f"{item}[{index}] = {df[item][index]}")
```